# Show that ratio of positive functions is decreasing/increasing

Tags: calculus

Good evening, I wonder how to show formally that this function is increasing or decreasing. I have tried anything I know of, but I was not able to procede.

Does anyone has an idea ?

$$
\frac{x^2a(a-1)}{(b + ax)^2}
$$
where $a \geq 2$,  $b \geq 1$ and $x > 0$

Comment: Take the derivative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you acquainted to calculus' results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show this function is increasing, without calculus:

A little algebraic manipulation shows
$$\frac x{b+ax}=\frac1a - \frac ba\left(\frac1 {b+ax}\right).$$
Now reason as follows, keeping in mind that $a\ge 2$ and $b\ge 1$: For $x>0$, the function $x\mapsto b+ax$ is increasing and positive. So its reciprocal is decreasing and positive. Multiplying by $-\frac ba$ makes it increasing, and it remains increasing after adding $\frac1a$ . Conclude that the function
$$
x\mapsto\frac x{b+ax}
$$
is increasing. It's clearly positive for $x>0$. So squaring it keeps it positive and increasing, and it remains so after multiplying by $a(a-1)$.

Comment: This is what I tried to do first and why I didn't think of calculus